# SQL Server Procedure: Substring and Convert Row to Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm new to sql and i have to accomplish the following task:

I got two tables:

Table1

```
 |   Nr | Binary           |
 ---------------------------
 |   1  | 111111111011010  |
 |   2  | 111111111011110  |
 |   3  |        ...       |
```

Table2

```
 |   Nr |
 -------- 
 |   1  |
 |   1  |
 |   1  |
 |   1  |
 |   1  |
 |   2  |
 |   2  |
 |   2  |
 |   3  |
 | ...  |
```

I want to alter Table2 (or create a new table), so it will be look like this:

```
 |   Nr | Binary |
 -----------------
 |   1  |    0   |
 |   1  |    1   |
 |   1  |    0   |
 |   1  |    1   |
 |   1  |    1   |
 |   2  |    0   |
 |   2  |    1   |
 |   2  |    1   |
 |  ... |   ...  |
```

Explanation:

Table2 has 4 times the "1" in Column "Nr" --> Substring the last 4 digits of Table1 Column "Binary" Row "1" and insert it row-wise in Table2 Column Binary where "Nr" is also 1

Table2 has 3 times the "2" in Column "Nr" --> Substring the last 3 digits of Table1 Column "Binary" Row "2" and insert it row-wise in Table2 Column Binary where "Nr" is also 1

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see the code attached. I used only numbers `1` and `2`, but it works in general :)

```
declare @table1 table (nr int, [binary] varchar(30))
insert into @table1 values (1, '111111111011010'), (2, '111111111011110')

declare @table2 table (nr int)
insert into @table2 values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(2)

select A.nr,
       SUBSTRING(B.[binary], LEN(B.[binary]) - A.rownum + 1, 1) AS [bit]
from (select rownum = row_number() over(partition by nr order by nr), nr from @table2) AS A
join @table1 AS B on A.nr = B.nr
```

Comment: my result looks like this: https://pasteboard.co/GLnjW2T.png (only zeros in the second column)

Comment: Then, you have zeros in the `Binary` column.

Comment: got it, it was my mistake... another 2 questions: Table2 has some more columns, how can i insert them too? why is the order wrong? (1,10,14...)

Comment: So include them in the subquery and then include them in outer query with `B.[col_name]`. To add ordeing, use simple `ORDER BY` clause on outer query.